# Variable from angular template shows up as undefined in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Ionic Framework and AngularJS to build a mobile app and I'm trying to the pass the ID of an item from the template into my controller but can't figure out why I'm receiving an undefined value. The value shows up on the template and in the rendered HTML, but when I attempt to call it in the controller it is empty

My template looks like this

```
<button class="button" ng-click="like({{sale.id}})">Like</button>   
<span>ID: {{sale.id}}</span>
```

`sale.id` is showing up on the page and when I inspect the element, it is inside the `like` function.

On my controller I have:

```
$scope.like = function(id) {
    console.log(id);
}
```

The `id` is showing up as undefined in the console.

Comment: It should simply be `like(sale.id)`, I think.

Comment: sale.id is $scope variable... pass it directly without parenthesis.

Comment: I know this is pretty old.. but I'm having a similar issue where I can display a variable within a template, but when I try to pass that same variable to a function, it is always undefined.  I've tried with and without string interpolation syntax {{}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `sale.id` without the `{{}}` - `ng-click` is a directive for which you don't have to use `{{}}` syntax.

Like so:

```
<button class="button" ng-click="like(sale.id)">Like</button>
```